# An Elementary complex number problem

Tags: complex-numbers

Suppose that $\dfrac{a+ib}{c-ib} = \dfrac{d+ie}{f + ig}$
                                    , where $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$ are positive real numbers.

Can this equality hold without $|e| = |g| $ ?

I tried expressing in polar form, but it seems not to work.

Comment: Why the moduli if $e, g$ are both positive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplifying we get,
$$(a+ib)(f+ig)=(c-ib)(d+ie)$$
or $$(af-bg)+i(bf+ag)=(cd+be)+i(ce-bd)$$

Equating real and imaginary parts, we get
$$af-bg=cd+be \Rightarrow a^2f-abg=acd+abe$$ and $$bf+ag=ce-bd \Rightarrow b^2f+abg=bce-b^2d $$

Adding we get, $$(a^2+b^2)f=(ac-b^2)d+(a+c)be \Rightarrow e=\frac{(a^2+b^2)f-(ac-b^2)d}{(a+c)b}$$

Similarly subtracting $$afc-bcg=c^2d+bce$$ from $$b^2f+abg=bce-b^2d $$ we get
$$(ac-b^2)f-(a+c)bg=(c^2+b^2)d \Rightarrow g=\frac{(ac-b^2)f-(c^2+b^2)d}{(a+c)b}$$

You can easily see that the equality does not require $$\color{blue}{|e|=|g|}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{2 + i}{3-i} = \frac{1+3i}{4 + 2i}.$$

Comment: Could you clarify what are the values of $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$ here?

Comment: The OP is asking about $\frac{a+i\color{red}{b}}{c-i\color{red}{b}}=\frac{d+ie}{f+ig}$.

Comment: Sorry for misreading, and thanks to both. Should have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It can: $$\frac{3+i}{3-i} = \frac{1+2i}{2+i}.$$